# How can I make the text use exactly the space that is avaliable to it?

Tags: css, javafx, fxml, hbox

The code that I currently have is:

```
<HBox fx:id="mainTagBody" id="mainTagBodyInOverview" alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      stylesheets="@/client/stylesheets/Global.css"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="client.scenes.TagInOverviewCtrl">

    <HBox fx:id="tagContain" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
        <Text fx:id="tagText" text="test" wrappingWidth="${tagContain.prefWidth}" />
    </HBox>

    <Button text="edit"/>

    <Button text="delete"/>

</HBox>
```

and this is how it looks:

No matter what I tried to do, the text would just either go through the edge, like this:

[image: text goes into the abyss]

and goes to the abyss, or like here:

[image: stretch]

extends the whole thing, moving the edge who knows where. I tried using the wrappingWidth in different ways, but none worked.

The way I intended for it to work is for the text to wrap when the tagContain hbox uses all available space, and avoid using exact numbers at all cost.

Comment: You should probably be using a [`Label`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Label.html), not [`Text`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html).  `Text` is a fixed-sized shape, whereas a label is a dynamically sizable [`Region`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html).

Comment: Where do you set or specify tagContain.prefWidth?

Comment: Checkout binding concept to influence the wrappingWidth during runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make JavaFX text wrap work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631744/how-to-make-javafx-text-wrap-work)

Comment: @Thomas if you look at this line in the code: `<Text fx:id="tagText" text="test" wrappingWidth="${tagContain.prefWidth}" />`, the last part is where `tagContain.prefWidth` is set. And it is exactly what they do in that page that you suggested, but just fxml instead of JavaFX code.

Comment: @jewelsea It worked using labels, thanks! Using the regionShape's default value and wrapText, after I added the prefWidth to the most outer hbox, the labels worked perfectly like I intended.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code to look like this:

```
<HBox fx:id="mainTagBody" id="mainTagBodyInOverview" alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      stylesheets="@/client/stylesheets/Global.css"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="client.scenes.TagInOverviewCtrl" prefWidth="300">
    <HBox fx:id="tagContain" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
        <Label fx:id="tagText" text="test" wrapText="true" />
    </HBox>
    <Button fx:id="editTagButton" text="edit" minWidth="60" />
    <Button fx:id="deleteTagButton" text="delete" minWidth="70" />
</HBox>
```

That solved my issue